# Vue.js - Less file import is throwing a 'module build failed' error with can't resolve '../assets/file.less'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, less, vue-cli-3, vue-loader

I'm trying to create an web application using Vue.js.
My project is built using Vue-Cli 3 and has the following structure:

```
-src
  -assets
  -components
    - first
       - Base.vue (*)
  - refer
    - less
       - user
          - register.less (*)
  - store
  - views
```

What I'm trying to do is to import `register.less` file on to `Base.vue` file.

Below is the code used in `Base.vue` file...

```
<style lang="less>
@import "../report/report.less";
</style>
```

If I try to run a server using `npm run serve`,
the following error is thrown:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import "../report/report.less";
^
Can't resolve '../report/report.less' in 'C:\Users\user\my_project\src\components\first'
      in C:\Users\user\my_project\src\components\first\Base.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=less& (line 95, column 0)
```

I'm guessing this error is saying that I'm using the wrong path for importing the less file. 
But I can't figure out how to fix it...

Please have a take a look... Thanks.

Comment: why are you importing report/report when in your file structure doesn't have report...

register.less

you are trying to import that 

but why import report.less

Comment: The error is saying `report/report.less` but you posted `less/user/register.less`. Which is it?

Comment: How about `@import "../../refer/less/user/register.less";` ?

Comment: oh... `@import "../../refer/less/user/register.less";` this indeed worked out well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are guessing right. The path must be relative. In your case you must go up one level still (via `..`). Use:

```html
<style lang="less>
@import "../../refer/less/user/register.less";
</style>
```